# Printing an array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to print an array of structs that contain two strings. However my print function does not print more than two indices of the array. I am not sure why because it seems to me that the logic is correct.

This is the main function

```
      const int MAX_LENGTH = 1024;

      typedef struct song
      {
          char songName[MAX_LENGTH];
          char artist[MAX_LENGTH];
      } Song;


      void getStringFromUserInput(char s[], int maxStrLength);
      void printMusicLibrary(Song library[], int librarySize);


      void printMusicLibraryTitle(void);
      void printMusicLibrary (Song library[], int librarySize);
      void printMusicLibraryEmpty(void);


      int main(void) {

      // Announce the start of the program
      printf("%s", "Personal Music Library.\n\n");
      printf("%s", "Commands are I (insert), S (sort by artist),\n"
       "P (print), Q (quit).\n");

      char response;
      char input[MAX_LENGTH + 1];
      int index = 0;

      do {
          printf("\nCommand?: ");
          getStringFromUserInput(input, MAX_LENGTH);

          // Response is the first character entered by user.
          // Convert to uppercase to simplify later comparisons.
          response = toupper(input[0]);

          const int MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE = 100;
          Song Library[MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE];

          if (response == 'I') {

               printf("Song name: ");
               getStringFromUserInput(Library[index].songName, MAX_LENGTH);


                printf("Artist: ");
                getStringFromUserInput(Library[index].artist, MAX_LENGTH);

                index++;


          }

          else if (response == 'P') {
               // Print the music library.
              int firstIndex = 0;

              if (Library[firstIndex].songName[firstIndex] == '\0') {
              printMusicLibraryEmpty();
              } else {
                  printMusicLibraryTitle();
                  printMusicLibrary(Library, MAX_LIBRARY_SIZE);
              }
```

This is my printing the library function

```
    // This function will print the music library
void printMusicLibrary (Song library[], int librarySize) {

    printf("\n");

    bool empty = true;

    for (int i = 0; (i < librarySize) && (!empty); i ++) {

        empty = false;

        if (library[i].songName[i] != '\0') {
            printf("%s\n", library[i].songName);
            printf("%s\n", library[i].artist);
            printf("\n");
        } else {
            empty = true;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In your `printMusicLibrary()` function, the `for` loop body never executes because you've set `empty` to `true` (so `(!empty)` is `false`) right before it.  Looks like setting it to `false` instead (before the loop) should work, since you already check for empty entries inside the loop.

Comment: Would be nice to have a code snipet that compiles, or at least that is complete: we do not have the complete `do {} while()` loop here

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is caused due to setting : `empty = true` outside the for loop and then checking `(!empty)` which will evaluate to `false`. What I am surprised by is how is it printing even two indices. You should set `empty = false` as you are already checking for the first index before the function call.

Answer (score 1):

The logic has two ways to terminate the listing:  1)  if the number of entries is reached, or 2) if any entry is empty.

I expect the second condition is stopping the listing before you expect.  Probably the array wasn't built as expected (I didn't look at that part), or something is overwriting an early or middle entry.

Answer (score 1):

you gave the definition as:

```
  typedef struct song
  {
      char songName[MAX_LENGTH];
      char artist[MAX_LENGTH];
  }Song;
```

the later, you write `if (library[i].songName[i] != '\0')` which really seems strange: why would you index the songname string with the same index that the lib?
so I would naturally expect your print function to be:

```
    // This function will print the music library
void printMusicLibrary (Song library[], int librarySize) {

   for (int i = 0; i < librarySize; i ++) {

       printf("%s\n%s\n\n", library[i].songName,
                            library[i].artist);

   }
}
```

note that you may skip empty song names by testing `library[i].songName[0] != '\0'` (pay attention to the 0), but I think it would be better not to add them in the list (does an empty song name make sens?)

(If you decide to fix that, note that you have an other fishy place: `if (Library[firstIndex].songName[firstIndex] == '\0')` with the same pattern)